# popup window in drupal

Tags: 6, ajax

I want a module to load in pop-up window. Ex. i have a module where the page callback will be a form. when user clicks on a link in my website. only the form has to load in the popup window like the lightbox 2 functionality.

i will generate a form in my custom module and i want the form to be displayed in the front-end of the site in a light box.. without other regions(header,footer,right,left) of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got answer from one of my friend. have to use page-[path].tpl.php created in theme page and use it with regular lightbox or any other js.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Popups](http://drupal.org/project/popups) module, it may be what you are looking for.

Comment: no... i will generate a form in my custom module and i want the form to be displayed in the frontend of the site in a light box.. without other regions(header,footer,right,left) of the page.

Comment: popups module has an API and instructions how you can use them in your module..

Answer (score 1):

There are basicly two alternatives:

1. Using the Ctoosl Modal module. This module, included on the [ctools](https://drupal.org/project/ctools) project, is the most popular way to popup modal forms on Drupal, with lots of addon modules (like [modal_forms](https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms)). [Here is a nice tutorial](http://drupion.com/blog/10-steps-creating-ctools-modal-window-drupal-7).
2. Using a custom module. You may find the following modules helpful:

   - [popup_message](https://drupal.org/project/popup_message) - which seems well supported.
   - [popup_announcement](https://drupal.org/project/popup_announcement) - this is a new module which seems closer to what you search for, with full html support, but with only a few downloads.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar using this: http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html